# Is there a better way to map the properties of one type to another?

Tags: typescript

We currently get objects from a database with a type like:

```
type SomeEntity = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: {d:string, e:string}[]
}
```

And I'm trying to get it into something like:

```
type Converted = {
    heading:string,
    copy: string,
    links: {label:string, url:string}[]
}
```

Currently, what I'm doing is creating a function that maps one to the other by doing something like:

```
function convert(data:SomeEntity)
{
    return {
        heading: data.a,
        copy: data.b,
        links: {label:data.c.d, url:label.data.e}[]
    } as Converted
}
```

It just seems so tedious. After doing some research, I saw that I can probably use the map function, but I'm still assigning one to another. I read a bit about Mapped types, but they seem more about augmenting rather than full on conversions.

Is there a better way to map one type to another type than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: Do you need this to be in TYPE scope or in RUNTIME scope?

Comment: I would say type scope. The data is pulled in during build time.

Comment: so your use function exclusively to get its return type? Ok.

Comment: Yes. What I'm doing is working. I'm just curious if there's a better, more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: also your code is wrong as `{a:string, b:string}` is not `{label:string, url:string}`

Comment: In one way or the other, this will always be manual work: Ie you have to define a mapping `a -> heading` and `b-> copy` and `c -> links`

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid repeating the properties for each type by using a schema library such as [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) ... Is that enough to go on or would you like a fleshed-out answer?

Comment: Same thought, if you need that runtime, use https://zod.dev/?id=transform , if type-only then there is no shorter way

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB8VDW) meet your needs? If so I could write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Dimava it's not wrong, it's just an example of what the expected transformation would be.

Comment: @derpirscher Yeah - I figured. I was kind of wondering if there was a way to write a generic function that could be used to convert any type to another. Even if there's  some manual work it would be less. But maybe not in the short term since I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @motto I can look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz it could. I think the answer is that it's already the shortest way. Maybe not the most generic, but it's fine. I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Yours is the shortest way *if* you're doing it for exactly one set of input and output types and the types are not deeply nested and don't have lots of properties.  As soon as you start mapping multiple types with lots of deeply nested properties, you'll want some more general version, such as the one I presented.  But I'm confused... what specifically are you looking for in an answer here?  (Note that "Thoughts?" isn't really a well-posed question for SO and that's partly why I'm not sure.) Could you [edit] to clarify the question?

Comment: @jcalz That's fair. I was asking (poorly) if there's a better way to map one type to another that is better than what I'm doing currently. I'll update my question.

Comment: Thanks. • "Better" is subjective and invites opinions; could you [edit] to clarify what it means to be "better"? Is it... shorter? More efficient? More reusable? Etc • Note that your example code does not work properly because `data.c` is of type `{a:string, b:string}[]` and not `{label:string, url:string}[]`; I guess you're aware of this but say it's not wrong because it's an example? Regardless could you [edit] to make it a [mre]? If you're asking for a shorter solution, then we need a fair comparison, and the current solution is short because it's pseudocode.

Comment: I know it doesn't work. It was just an example. I said "something" like this. I didn't feel like I needed to map everything out exactly to get the point across. It's all good though. I don't think there's a better solution. I thought maybe there might be a way using some typescript builtins that I wasn't aware of that would allow remapping easier. Or maybe using a mapped type I could transform it that way. It doesn't seem to be the case though.

Comment:  Your edit still doesn’t work; you need to map the array instead of using a bracket suffix. A broken example is distracting (e.g, “help me do addition like 1+1=3”) so if you don’t want others to pay attention to it, it’s easier to just fix it than it is to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand briefly on the use of a schema library such as [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) –

The idea would be to define your schemas and use the `transform` functionality to remap the keys. It would preserve the shape of your data (and potentially allow funkier transformations like Date extraction) without you needing to duplicate the type declarations.

```js
const SomeEntityLink = z.object({
  a: z.string(),
  b: z.string()
}).transform(
  ({ a: label, b: url }) => ({ label, url })
);

const SomeEntity = z.object({
  a: z.string(),
  b: z.string(),
  c: z.array(SomeEntityLink)
}).transform(
  ({ a: heading, b: copy, c: links }) => ({ heading, copy, links })
);

const parsed = SomeEntity.parse({ a: "foo", b: "bar", c: [] });
// { heading: "foo", copy: "bar", links: [] }
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zod-forked-0fn1gf?file=/src/index.ts)

It is perhaps *marginally* less tedious at best but I would recommend it for bringing external data into the fold because Zod will tell you loudly if there is a schema violation.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks!